# Load rows in redshift with record size greater than 4 MB?

Tags: json, copy, logic, amazon-redshift, etl

I am using the copy command of redshift to load json file into redshift but I receive the error

**ERROR:  The total size of the json object exceeds the max limit of 4194304 bytes
DETAIL:

---

error:  The total size of the json object exceeds the max limit of 4194304 bytes
  code:      8001**

I can understand that redshift has some problem in reading json objects with size greater than 4 MB
But there should be a work around . Any help would be great . 
Thanks in advance

`copy test.orders from 's3://path_to_my_file/myfile.json' 
 WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=MY_KEY' COMPUPDATE OFF TIMEFORMAT 'auto' DATEFORMAT 'auto' BLANKSASNULL TRUNCATECOLUMNS ACCEPTINVCHARS MAXERROR 100 format as json 'auto';`

Comment: I know its late but had you managed to figure out the solution?